# How to avoid Retrofit to encode single quotation mark in HTTP Url?

Tags: android, retrofit2, url-encoding

I want to send a request to an api with a URL that includes single quotation mark characters. I'm using retrofit2.

**I want this url to reach to api:** http://someapp.somecompany.com/api/contents/inc()?$filter=_Id%20eq%20'57fb60534421dd35544b27a9'

I tried @Query and @QueryMap annotations with (encoded=true) and also (encoded=false) properties but none of my tries worked.

***MyClient (Interface)***

```
@PUT("api/contents/inc()")
Call<Object> addLike(@QueryMap(encoded =true) Map<String,String>  options);
```

***MainActivity (Activity)***

```
Map<String,String> likeMap = new HashMap<>();
likeMap.put("$filter","_Id%20eq%20'57fb60534421dd35544b27a9'");
Call<Object> addLikeCall = myClient.addLike(likeMap);
addLikeCall.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {.....});
```

This code gives me this output:

--> PUT http://someapp.somecompany.com/api/contents/inc()?$filter=_Id%20eq%20%2757fb60534421dd35544b27a9%27 http/1.1 (0-byte body)

<-- 500 Internal Server Error http://someapp.somecompany.com/api/contents/inc()?$filter=_Id%20eq%20%2757fb60534421dd35544b27a9%27 (132ms, 36-byte body)

How can i avoid retrofit to encode my single quotation mark in url ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `'` character in your url with `%27` manually if it solves your proplem.

Other ascii encoding is in this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: I just want the opposite of your suggestion. I don't want my `'` character to be replaced by `%27` by retrofit. I tried to replace `%27` substring with `'` character at interceptor class but couldn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: You cant do this unless you have convention by your server side to change it to some other character and reverse it in server side. Uou cant have these characters in your url without being changed automatically. Its the web protocol you cant have these characters in your url

Comment: I dont think that internal server error is becuase of that single quotation becuase they are reversed automatically at the server side by web service providers

Comment: There is some excepetion in the server side .

Comment: I have a friend sitting next to me and developing the same application for ios devices. His request responds successful but mine doesn't. The only difference in our requests is that quotation mark encoding. This situation forced me to think that the problem could only because of encoding.